# iOS : UIScrollView paging not working properly

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I'm adding `AsyncImageView` into `UIScrollView` to load images from web, its working fine, there are 8 images i've added. Problem is of `paging` I've enabled `pagingEnable` to `YES` but it won't come as per I want, I'm trying to setting it `contentOffset` with different `x` but it won't any effects. I want that each image should come in `center` of `UIScrollView` when I scroll or choose `next` or `previous` option.

This is the code where I'm adding images to `UIScrollView`

> arrImgUrls is an NSArray
>
> _currentImage, _imageCount are integers

```
-(void)setImagesToScrollView
{
    [btnPrev setEnabled:NO];

    _currentImage = 0;

    _imageCount = [arrImgUrls count];

    int x=20;
    int y=0;
    int w=213;
    int h=160;

    for (int i=0; i<[arrImgUrls count]; i++) 
    {
        AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
        [asyncImageView setDelegate:self];
        [asyncImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];        
        NSString *urlImage = [arrImgUrls objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImage];
        [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:url];
        [asyncImageView release];
        [scrollImages addSubview:asyncImageView];
        x=(x+w)+10;
    }

    scrollImages.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x, scrollImages.frame.size.height);
}
```

This is code I used to show `previous` or `next` images in `UIScrollView`.

```
-(IBAction)prevImage:(id)sender
{    
    _currentImage--;

    [btnNext setEnabled:YES];
    
    if (_currentImage<=0)
    {
        _currentImage = 0;
        [btnPrev setEnabled:NO];
    }

    [scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake((_currentImage*imageWidth)+10, 0) animated:NO];
}

-(IBAction)nextImage:(id)sender
{    
    _currentImage++;

    [btnPrev setEnabled:YES];

    if (_imageCount-1 == _currentImage)
    {
        [btnNext setEnabled:NO];
    }

    [scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_currentImage*imageWidth, 0) animated:NO];
}
```

All images loaded and added to `UIScrollView` only problem is to show it in `center` when user `scrolls` or do `previous` or `next`.

Please point me where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure that `_currentImage` is maintain properly or not?

Now try following for next image

```
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = (imageWidth * _currentImage) +10;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES]; // NO if you don't want animation
```

Instead of this line

```
[scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_currentImage*imageWidth+10, 0) animated:NO];
```

& for previous image

```
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = (imageWidth * _currentImage) - 10;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES]; // NO if you don't want animation
```

and here one nice example just like you want

[Image gallary](https://github.com/alexrepty/Paging-Enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews/downloads)

Comment: Not yet! :( but the example you've linked is good and same as I want, I'm taking help from it.

Comment: @Hemang ok...try it & tell me if you solved it...good luck & one thing i have noticed in your question im nextimg you have written [scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake((_currentImage*imageWidth)+10, 0) animated:NO]; here instead of +10 make -10 & innext image use +10 try it & tell me if it worked

Comment: PRJ, Solved it !! Spend a day in this :(. Your example makes it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with frame that you are setting for AsyncImageView. You must be familiar how the paging working. It checks for rect you have assigned to scrollview & it scroll to the center of the scrollview hence you might seeing the image are placed towards left or right side not aligned center. Try setting frame AsyncImageView as x= 0 & width = 320 & see the behavior of the scrollview.