# iOS : How to do proper paging in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, custom-paging, scroll-paging

I've a `UIScrollView` of size (320,160). I'm adding some `UIImageView` into it, which are of size (213,160). The first `UImageView` starting from 54 (x) and so on, I've added a space of 5.0 in between each `UIImageView`. I've also enabled `pagingEnable` in `IB` & in `coding`. What my problem is its not properly working as per its property! When I scroll it should show me `UIImageViews` in each single `page` instead it showing me something like [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOn6Q.png) I want output something like this [see output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHWNG.png)

Where I'm doing wrong? I also having function of`<` (previous) & `>` (next) there to show images. I've asked one question yesterday which was I accepted however my requirement is little change and it won't become my solution. [see my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12722254/1603234)

Is there any special property that I've to set, or some logic I should implement? All examples I've checked and tried but I find that my requirement is some special. Point me! Thanks.

**EDITED:**

```
- (void) setImages
{
CGFloat contentOffset = 0.0f;

    for (int i=0; i<[arrImgUrls count]; i++) 
    {
        CGRect imageViewFrame = CGRectMake(contentOffset, 0.0f, 213, scrollImages.frame.size.height);
        AsyncImageView *asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];
        [asyncImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        NSString *urlImage = [arrImgUrls objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImage];
        [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:url];
        [scrollImages addSubview:asyncImageView];
    contentOffset += asyncImageView.frame.size.width+increment;
        [asyncImageView release];
}

    scrollImages.contentSize = CGSizeMake([arrImgUrls count] * scrollImages.frame.size.width, scrollImages.frame.size.height);
    scrollImages.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollImages.clipsToBounds = NO;
}

-(IBAction)prevImage:(id)sender
{    
     _currentImage--;

     [btnNext setEnabled:YES];

     if (_currentImage==0)
     {
         [btnPrev setEnabled:NO];
         [scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake((_currentImage*imageWidth), 0) animated:YES];
         return;
     }

     NSLog(@"previous:mult %d inc %d current %d",_currentImage*imageWidth,increment*_currentImage,_currentImage);

     int nextImage=_currentImage+2;

     [scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake((((_currentImage*imageWidth)-(increment*_currentImage)))+(nextImage*increment), 0) animated:YES];
 }

-(IBAction)nextImage:(id)sender
{    
   _currentImage++;

   NSLog(@"next:mult %d inc %d current %d",_currentImage*imageWidth,increment*_currentImage,_currentImage);

  [scrollImages setContentOffset:CGPointMake((_currentImage*imageWidth)+(increment*_currentImage), 0) animated:YES];

  [btnPrev setEnabled:YES];

  if (_imageCount-1 == _currentImage)
 {
    [btnNext setEnabled:NO];
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your scroll view any paging at all (but only normal scrolling) or is your problem that you images don't show in the middle when scrolling/paging stops?

Comment: Yes @Kai, exactly. When I scroll images don't show in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paging scroll views alway page multiples of their frame size. So in your example paging is always +320.

This behavior is good if you have content portions matching the frame of the scroll view.

What you have to do, is giving your scroll view a width of 213 and set its `clipsToBounds` property to `NO`. 
After that your scroll view pages exactly how you want and you see what's left and right outside the frame. 
Additionally you have to do a trick to make this left and right area delegate touches to the scroll view.

It's greatly explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220605/53313).

Comment: It's working but removing all clipsToBounds doesn't helped. Cells are being removed once they are out of collection view.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to set scrollview content size.

make sure that you have set the content size to fit N number of images.

if you want to scrollview to scroll for 10 images with an image on each page 
set scrollView `contentSize` as

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320 * 10,200)];
```